# Como contar os objetos presentes na imagem com PHP?

Tags: php, imagem, matriz, processamento-de-imagens

A foto original do feijão é essa:

[image: objetos]

Diminui a resolução da foto, já apliquei um filtro para ficar em escala de cinza e aumentei o contraste ao máximo para ficar preto e branco.
Depois examinei a cor de cada um dos pixels e montei uma array matriz.
Se eu iterar sobre essa array e escrever um 0 para os pixels brancos e um x para os pretos, eu consigo o seguinte:

[image: matriz]

A partir daí estou tentando encontrar uma maneira de contar quantas porções de x tem nessa matriz. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: A resposta do Anderson é mais que suficiente. Mas, se quiser aprofundar, a solução para N tipos de objetos pode estar na **Transformada de Hough**. Há métodos baseados na transformada para contagem de glóbulos vermelhos no sangue e urina (formas arredondadas) bem como encontrar formas retangulares. E muitos outros casos. Papers de exemplo: "_Automatic Red Blood Cell Counting Using Hough Transform_", "_Development Algorithm to Count Blood Cells inUrine Sediment using ANN and Hough Transform_" e "_Rectangle Detection based on a Windowed Hough Transform_".

Comment: Caso os feijões estejam juntos (se tocando) ou sobrepostos, A Transformada [Watershed](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(processamento_de_imagem)) pode ser utilizada. [Este desafio do Codegolf: Counting Grains of Rice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40831/71194) mostra algumas maneiras de contar grãos com segmentação de imagem em várias linguagens.

Answer (score 47):

Vale ressaltar que nesta resposta prezou-se mais pela simplicidade da solução a que a performance da mesma.

## Lógica

O mais natural de se pensar é: vou percorrer todos os valores da minha matriz verificando se é 1, se for, incrementa a quantidade de feijões. Um problema bem óbvio é que desta forma irá ser considerado, para cada 1 do feijão, como um feijão diferente. No exemplo dado mais abaixo, ao invés de resultar em 3 feijões, resultaria em 88 (total de 1 na matriz). Uma forma simples de contornar isso é, quando encontrado um valor 1 na matriz, substitua-o por 2 e verifique os valores periféricos, isto é, os quatro valores laterais e os quatro valores diagonais, buscando por outros valores 1. Se achar, repita o processo, substituindo-os por 2 e verificando os respectivos valores periféricos. Desta forma, para cada valor 1 encontrado no laço, a área do feijão referente a este valor terá seus valores atualizados para 2, assim, ao continuar com o laço percorrendo a matriz, não mais encontrará valores 1 para o mesmo feijão e sim valores 2, ignorando-os.

## Solução

**Foto considerada na solução**

Foi considerado uma foto 50x50 contendo 3 feijões.

```
$photo = [
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
];
```

Definidos a variável referente a quantidade de feijões:

```
$beans = 0;
```

Percorremos a matriz inteira, buscando por valores 1:

```
// Percorre as linhas da foto
for ($i = 0; $i < count($photo); $i++)
{

  // Percorre as colunas da foto
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($photo[$i]); $j++)
  {

    // Encontrou um feijão
    if ($photo[$i][$j] == 1)
    {
      // Incrementa a quantidade de feijões
      $beans++;

      // Atualiza a área do feijão por 2
      expandBeanArea($photo, $i, $j);
    }

  }
}
```

Nós definiremos a função `expandBeanArea` de forma que ela seja recursiva e consiga atingir toda a área na matriz referente a um feijão, substituindo os valores 1 por 2. Segue a função:

```
function expandBeanArea (&$photo, $i, $j)
{
  if ($i < 0 || $i >= count($photo)) return;
  if ($j < 0 || $j >= count($photo[0])) return;

  if ($photo[$i][$j] == 1)
    {
        $photo[$i][$j] = 2;

        expandBeanArea($photo, $i-1, $j-1);
        expandBeanArea($photo, $i-1, $j);
        expandBeanArea($photo, $i-1, $j+1);
        expandBeanArea($photo, $i, $j-1);
        expandBeanArea($photo, $i, $j+1);
        expandBeanArea($photo, $i+1, $j-1);
        expandBeanArea($photo, $i+1, $j);
        expandBeanArea($photo, $i+1, $j+1);
    }
}
```

Se definirmos uma saída:

```
echo "Encontrados {$beans} feijões na foto.";
```

Teremos a mensagem: `Encontrados 3 feijões na foto.`

Veja funcionando no [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yxmb-0hks).

> **Nota 1**: É importante, para esta solução, que o parâmetro `$photo` da função `expandBeanArea` seja passado por referência. Isso se dá ao fato que as alterações feitas sobre esta variável devem influenciar nas próximas iterações do laço executado.

---

> **Nota 2**: Também é indispensável que o laço que percorre a matriz seja feito com a instrução `for`, pois a instrução `foreach` armazena, de alguma forma, o valor inicial da matriz e o utiliza em todas as iterações e mesmo que seu valor se altere (inclusive passando por referência, vide **Nota 1**), todas as iterações são baseadas no valor inicial, gerando um resultado errado.

---

> **Nota 3**: Seguindo esta lógica, será considerado como um feijão cada valor ou região de 1 que esteja cercado com valores 0. Esta prática não é aconselhável para o sistema em produção, pois qualquer ruído presente poderia gerar falsos resultados. Uma forma de contornar isso seria, no processo de substituir os valores por 2, contar também a quantia de valores 1 que estão sendo substituídos para o mesmo feijão e, desta forma, apenas considerar que é, de fato, um feijão, quando a quantia passar um valor limite pré-definido.

---

## Eliminando Ruídos

Como citado na **Nota 3**, o programa é muito sensível a qualquer ruído presente na foto. Então, para implementar a solução sugerida na mesma, de contar a quantia de 1 em cada feijão, de forma a definir uma área mínima na foto, podemos fazer:

```
function expandBeanArea (&$photo, $i, $j)
{
  if ($i < 0 || $i >= count($photo)) return;
  if ($j < 0 || $j >= count($photo[0])) return;

  $area = 0;

  if ($photo[$i][$j] == 1)
    {
        $photo[$i][$j] = 2;

        $area++;

        $area += expandBeanArea($photo, $i-1, $j-1);
        $area += expandBeanArea($photo, $i-1, $j);
        $area += expandBeanArea($photo, $i-1, $j+1);
        $area += expandBeanArea($photo, $i, $j-1);
        $area += expandBeanArea($photo, $i, $j+1);
        $area += expandBeanArea($photo, $i+1, $j-1);
        $area += expandBeanArea($photo, $i+1, $j);
        $area += expandBeanArea($photo, $i+1, $j+1);
    }

  return $area;
}
```

Perceba a inserção da variável `$area` sendo responsável por armazenar a quantia de valores 1 de cada feijão. Agora, enquanto percorremos a matriz, fazemos a condição:

```
// Percorre as linhas da foto
for ($i = 0; $i < count($photo); $i++)
{

  // Percorre as colunas da foto
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($photo[$i]); $j++)
  {

    // Encontrou um feijão
    if ($photo[$i][$j] == 1)
    {
      // Verifica a área do feijão na foto
      $area = expandBeanArea($photo, $i, $j);

      // Verifica se a área é maior que o limiar pré-definido
      if ($area >= 20)
      {
        // Incrementa a quantidade de feijões
        $beans++;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Desta forma, se não for encontrado no mínimo 20 valores 1 compondo uma mesma área da foto, a mesma é considerada ruído e não contabilizada na contagem de feijões.

> **Nota 4**: O valor 20 é hipotético neste exemplo e deve ser definido conforme a necessidade do seu projeto. Faça uma estimativa da área média ocupada pelos feijões para obter esse valor.

Veja o processo de expansão, substituindo os valores 1 por 2, na animação abaixo. Perceba que a contagem do feijão se dá apenas quando a área inteira é expandida, isso, pois, será considerado o número de 1 encontrados, contabilizando como feijão apenas de a área for igual ou superior a 20. Aproveitei e incluí no exemplo alguns pequenos ruídos, caracterizados por áreas menores de 1 espalhadas pela foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de criar um exemplo no php fiddle, caso não se importe :)

Comment: Executou? Tentei aqui antes e dava timeout. Se sim, obrigado.

Comment: Um problema que encontrei é que se tiver qualquer "sujeira" na foto, por exemplo a matriz ter um "1" perdido em qualquer lugar, ele incrementa na quantidade de feijões. Daria para fazer esse tratamento para melhoria.

Comment: Sim, vide nota 3 da resposta.

Comment: Um tamanho minimo da área em expandBeanArea talvez?

Comment: @AckLay, implementei a solução na resposta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss me desculpa, não li a questão do ruido na nota 3. Gostei da explicação. +1 Ps.:Fiz uma app em 2014 que trabalhei com tratamento de imagem porém em JAVA. A ideia é calcular a quantidade de desfolha de uma folha. Veja e entenda melhor: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=upvision.bioleaf&hl=pt_BR

Comment: Muito boa resposta. Ganhou meu +1. :) Apesar de vc ter total razão sobre a importância do tratamento de ruído, a minha opinião é de que esse tratamento deveria ser feito no pré-processamento da imagem e não na contagem de feijões. A razão é que o AP pode, algum dia, precisar tomar outras decisões a respeito dos feijões (por exemplo, localizá-los na imagem), e assim ele precisaria replicar essa lógica de tratamento de ruídos em outra função.

Comment: Há formas de fazer isso diretamente na imagem original, usando [filtros de suavização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtro_linear_de_suaviza%C3%A7%C3%A3o), [operações morfológicas](http://pt.slideshare.net/lenonfachiano/processamento-morfolgico-de-imagens) e até mesmo usando outros tipos de [limiarização](https://sites.google.com/site/imgprocgpu/limiarizacao).

Comment: Com certeza. Até diria que PHP não seria a linguagem ideal para esse tipo de processo. Python seria uma opção muito melhor, mas dependendo da necessidade, PHP faz o trabalho.

Answer (score 12):

Se você puder instalar uma extensão é possível fazer com [php-opencv](http://phpopencv.org/).

Primeiro, com a imagem com nome `feijao.jpg` salva, podemos lê-la em tons de cinza.

```
$image  = imread('feijao.jpg', IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

Como os feijões são pretos, é bem fácil isolar eles do restante da imagem, bastando aplicar um threshold com um valor bem pequeno. No exemplo, eu usei 80, para que todo pixel menor que 80 virasse foreground e maior que 80 virasse background (o `THRESH_BINARY_INV` transforma o preto em branco e vice-versa).

```
$binary = null;
threshold($image, $binary, 80, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

Temos como resultado desse processamento a seguinte imagem:

[image: Imagem preto e branco]

Agora vamos achar todos os feijões usando a função `findContours` do opencv. Na biblioteca a função se chama `findContoursWithoutHierarchy` porque não retorna o terceiro parâmetro que a função original retorna, as hierarquias entre os contornos.

```
$contours = null;
findContoursWithoutHierarchy($binary, $contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Com isso temos uma lista de contornos. Mas cada contorno pode ter dezenas de pontos, nesse caso, pra ficar mais fácil trabalhar, vamos calcular os retângulos que englobam cada conjunto de contornos que achamos. Pra isso usamos a função `boundingRect`.

```
$boxes = array_map(function ($contour) {
    return boundingRect($contour);
}, $contours);
```

Desenhando os retângulos encontrados, temos o seguinte resultado.
[image: Imagem com bounding box nos objetos encontrados]

Mas se contarmos a quantidade de boxes vamos ver que o resultado é 9 (e não 8 como esperávamos). Olhando os boxes, existe 1 extremamente pequeno (com altura e largura de 1px). Vamos filtrar então os resultados com pixels muito pequenos chutando um valor mínimo.

```
$boxes = array_filter($boxes, function ($box) {
    return $box->width > 20 && $box->height > 20;
});
```

Aqui removemos todo mundo que tem menos de 20px de altura ou de largura. A altura e a largura média dos retângulos corretos está em 120px, então é uma aposta razoável.

Agora basta imprimir o resultado:

```
echo 'Encontrados ' . count($boxes) . ' feijões na foto.';
```

E vamos ter o resultado correto:

> Encontrados 8 feijões na foto.

PS: Eu omiti algumas partes do código para focar só no essencial, coloquei o código completo nesse [gist](https://gist.github.com/begnini/7442c744472eb9137d2f20c551434c3f)