# Reconhecimento de Padrões em Python

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens

Bom dia pessoal
Estou desenvolvendo um trabalho para faculdade na qual preciso reconhecer imagens com Python, porem o professor deseja que o algoritmo de reconhecimento não pertença a uma livraria já feita como OpenCV.
Pesquisando um pouco só achei informações de livrarias já feitas, o único que achei e é em uma pergunta anterior sobre o mesmo tema os algoritmos SIFT + KNN, mas eu queria saber se tem mais algoritmos similares que eu possa implementar em Python.

Comment: Tem algo em PHP, não tenho certeza se é o que você precisa, mas já é uma ideia.  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183508/como-contar-os-objetos-presentes-na-imagem-com-php/314037?r=SearchResults#314037

Comment: Nao tem a ver com a tecnologia(PHP) porem sua resposta junto da o do jsbueno me deram uma ideia da complexidade do tema e irei usar uma biblioteca ja feita, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconhecimento de padrões não é algo trivial - 
A não ser que o curso seja *sobre* isso, e nesse caso você deve estar aprendendo sobre classificadores, machine learning e os algoritmos específicos, não tem nem sentido tentar criar isso de zero sem usar uma biblioteca ("livraria" como os brasileiros escrevemos) que já faça isso, ou pelo menos tenha as fundações para isso, como o tensorflow.

Se é parte da própria disciplina, você deve ter uma ideia melhor de por onde quer começar ou um pouco de código que já tenha feito.

Uma livraria legal que tem suporte a carregar imagens, e muitos dos algoritmos usados em pré-processamento e segmentação é a leptonica - ela é em C, mas pode ser usada a partir de Python com "ctypes". (eu fiz um wrapper usando ctypes uma vez mas não tenho mantido atualizado - deve dar algum trabalho pra configurar corretamente - https://github.com/jsbueno/pyleptonica  (acabei de olhar, não está sequer ajustada para Python 3 - shame on me) - De qualquer forma, independente de ser possível atualizar esse wrapper ou realizar as chamadas com ctypes bruto, a leptonica é um bom começo para se encontrar os algoritmos de base que vão permitir a classificação de imagens - vale olhar a documentação da biblioteca original.
https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porem o primeiro link esta quebrado pois escreveu github como githib, no caso irei seguir suas dicas e usar uma biblioteca como base.