# Problema com matrizes em Python

Tags: python, matriz

Olá, gostaria de ajuda. Eu tenho que gerar, em Python, uma matriz com um número l de linhas e um número c de colunas, e calcular o somatório dos elementos da diagonal principal e da secundária. O somatório é feito corretamente, mas ele salva cada linha da matriz por cima da linha anterior, assim, quando eu vou imprimir a matriz, ela só repete a última linha várias vezes. Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei muito grato. Segue o código:

```
# Programa para processar e imprimir uma matriz l x c
# Calcular o somatório dos elementos das diagonais principal e secundária
l = int(input("Insira o número de linhas: "))
c = int(input("Insira o número de colunas: "))
matriz = [[0] * c] * l
soma1 = int(0)
soma2 = int(0)
for i in range(0, l):
    for j in range(0, c):
        matriz[i][j] = int(input(f"Insira o elemento {j+1} da linha {i+1}: "))
    soma1 = soma1 + matriz[i][i]
    soma2 = soma2 + matriz[i][l - 1 - i]
print("\nElementos da matriz: ")
for i in range(0, l):
    print(matriz[i])
if l == c:
    print("\nSomatório dos elementos da diagonal principal =", soma1)
    print("Somatório dos elementos da diagonal secundária =", soma2)
else:
    print("A matriz não é quadrada, logo não possui diagonais.")
```

Como vocês podem ver pelo código, sou bem iniciante na linguagem, por isso gostaria que, se possível, não resolvessem o problema com comandos muito complexos, mas se for necessário faço o possível para entender. Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bom, não acredito que o que vou por seja complexo, vou por alguns comentários para caso você não entenda.

```
# PEGUEI SEU CÓDIGO PARA FACILITAR VOU DEIXAR ELE MAIS EXTENSO MESMO QUE NÃO ESTEJA 
OTIMIZADO
# Programa para processar e imprimir uma matriz l x c
# Calcular o somatório dos elementos das diagonais principal e secundária
l = int(input("Insira o número de linhas: "))
c = int(input("Insira o número de colunas: "))
matriz = [] #vou apenas descomplicar colocando abaixo uma lista por linha

somaprincipal = 0 # meio desnecessário fazer o casting afinal, python não é uma linguagem fortemente tipada
somasecundaria = 0

for i in range(0, l):
    matriz.append([]) #adiciona uma lista sempre que percorre o loop, mas do seu jeito é mais rápido
    for j in range(0, c):
        matriz[i].append(int(input(f"Insira o elemento {j+1} da linha {i+1}: ")))
        if i == j: # só soma quando o número da linha é o mesmo número da coluna.
            somaprincipal += matriz[i][j] 

for i in range(-1,(-l-1), -1): # percorre a lista do último item ao primeiro
    for j in range(-1,(-c-1), -1): # o mesmo de cima
        if i == j:
            somasecundaria += matriz[i][j]


print("\nElementos da matriz: ")
for i in range(0, l):
    print(*matriz[i]) #printa a matriz sem mostrar os colchetes nem vírgulas
if l == c:
    print("\nSomatório dos elementos da diagonal principal =", somaprincipal)
    print("Somatório dos elementos da diagonal secundária =", somasecundaria)
else:
    print("A matriz não é quadrada, logo não possui diagonais.")
```

Assim resolve o problema, entretanto o problema do seu código é que listas são mutáveis, dê um print toda vez que você mudar/adicionar um item da lista para você ver que do jeito que o código está, sempre que você modificar um elemento ele vai modificar o resto e assim por diante, por isso eu fui adicionar lista por lista, para não ter esse problema de elas estarem "linkadas" pois quando você fez isso

```
matriz = [[0] * c] * l
```

apenas fez com que o endereço na memória da lista fosse para cada um dos indices da lista, espero que tenha entendido.

esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408472/print-memory-address-of-python-variable) pode ajudar para você ver/entender que as listas foram apenas copiados o endereço e não foram criadas outras.

Comment: caso não consiga abrir o link corretamente (eu não consegui após o envio) está aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408472/print-memory-address-of-python-variable

Answer (score 0):

O problema está nessa linha:

```
matriz = [[0] * c] * l
```

Vamos dividi-la em dois comandos para facilitar a explicação:

```
linha = [0] * c
matriz = [linha] * l
```

Ao criar a lista interna (chamada de `linha` no exemplo) usando `[0] * c`, o código está usando o operador de multiplicação de referências. É criada uma nova lista com um total de `c` referências ao objeto `0`. Não são criados outros objetos `0` mas isso não é problema neste caso pois `0` é `int` e `int`s são imutáveis no python.

Ao pegar essa lista e multiplicar `[linha] * l`, o mesmo acontece, porém são criadas `l` referências à mesma lista `linha`. A sua variável matriz então se torna uma lista com várias referências, todas apontando para a mesma lista...

O problema é que listas são mutáveis. Ao modificar um elemento da lista interna:

```
matriz[i][j] = int(input(....))
```

Todas as linhas serão afetadas, pois na verdade existe somente uma única linha, referenciada múltiplas vezes!

Uma forma de resolver é forçar a criação de múltiplas listas independentes:

```
matriz = [[0 for x in c] for y in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Observação: Só podemos operar diagonais de uma matriz se a mesma for QUADRADA**.

Em outras palavras, só faz sentido falar em diagonais se o número de linhas da matriz for `igual` ao número de colunas. Caso contrário, não faz sentido algum falar em diagonais.

Quando temos uma matriz `A(1 x 1)`, dizemos que a matriz A é `quadrada e de ordem "1"` e quando temos uma matriz `B(2 x 2)`, dizemos que a matriz B é `quadrada e de ordem "2"` e assim, sucessivamente.

Portanto, quando estamos operando com matrizes quadradas, basta especificarmos a sua `ordem` para imediatamente subtender o número de linhas e de colunas que, por conseguinte, são iguais.

Quando o autor da pergunta diz que deseja calcular a `soma dos elementos da diagonal principal` ele está se referindo ao [traço](https://www.maxwell.vrac.puc-rio.br/82/82_PRINCIPAL.HTM#:%7E:text=Ou%20seja%2C%20o%20tra%C3%A7o%20de,elementos%20de%20sua%20diagonal%20principal.) da matriz e quando ele diz que deseja calcular a `soma dos elementos da diagonal secundária` ele está se referindo ao [anti-traço](https://dspace.uevora.pt/rdpc/bitstream/10174/14751/2/Tese%20Doutoramento%20-%20Sistemas%20din%C3%A2micos%20em%20%C3%81lgebras%20de%20Matrizes.pdf) da matriz.

Tanto o `traço` como o `anti-traço` só podem ser calculados se a matriz for quadrada.

Para resolvermos esta questão podemos implementar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
import numpy as np

# Capturando e tratando a ordem da matriz quadrada.
while True:
    try:
        m = int(input('Digite a ordem da matriz: '))
        if m < 1:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')

# Montando a matriz quadrada de ordem "m".
matrizTemp = list()
for c in range(1, m + 1):
    linha = list()
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        # Capturando e tratando os valores de cada elemento da matriz.
        while True:
            try:
                valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i}º elemento de {c}ª linha: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros!\033[m')
        linha.append(valor)
    matrizTemp.append(linha)

# Organizando de forma espacial a matriz.
matriz = np.array(matrizTemp)
matriz_in = np.fliplr(matriz)

# Calculando o traço e o antitraço da matriz.
traco = np.trace(matriz)
antitraco = np.trace(matriz_in)

# Exibindo os resultados.
print(f'\033[32mA matriz gerada é:\n{matriz}')
print(f'A soma dos elementos da diagonal principal é: {traco}')
print(f'A soma dos elementos da diagonal secundária é: {antitraco}\033[m')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/crjzcxtx-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que quando executamos o algoritmo recebemos a mensagem; `Digite a ordem da matriz`. Neste momento devemos digitar um número `inteiro` e `maior que zero`. a partir desse momento devemos digitar cada elemento da matriz e, em seguida, pressionar `enter`.

Depois de termos digitado todos os elementos da matriz o algoritmo montará e exibirá a matriz, além de calcular o seu `traço` e `anti-traço` respectivamente.

[Veja aqui](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) o significado do do termo `fliplr` utilizado no código...

```
matriz_in = np.fliplr(matriz)
```

...observe também [aqui](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html#:%7E:text=trace,-numpy.&text=Return%20the%20sum%20along%20diagonals,%2Boffset%5D%20for%20all%20i.) as aplicações do termo `trace` utilizado nos códigos...

```
traco = np.trace(matriz)
```

e..

```
antitraco = np.trace(matriz_in)
```

**Observação**

Perceba que quanto maior for a `ordem` da matriz quadrada, maior será o `total de elementos` que deverão ser inseridos na matriz.